# Setting fields in one table based on criteria in another

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I'm going to ask this question in as clear a fashion as I can. It is quite confusing so I apologize beforehand if it comes across unclear:

I have a group of tables: Table1, Table2, Table3

Each of these tables has a column "Age"

I want to create a table that checks to see if the age column contains any record in the "Age" column for each table is greater than 60, and if it is, set a record in the new column equal to "RED." I would also like to specify some other criteria to set the column equal to "Yellow" and "Green" as well; however, one step at a time.

Something like this:

Table    |  Age

Table 1 | Red

Table 2 | Yellow

Table 3 | Green

Any help available is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
select case when max(t1.age) > 60 then 'RED' else 'GREEN' end table1_age, 
            case when max(t2.age) > 60 then 'RED' else 'GREEN' end table2_age, 
            case when max(t3.age) > 60 then 'RED' else 'GREEN' end table3_age
      from (select max(age) age from table1) t1
           cross join (select max(age) age from table2) t2
           cross join (select max(age) age from table2) t3;
```

or

```
select 'table 1' tabl,
        case when max(age) > 60 then 'RED' else 'GREEN' end 
  from  table1 t1
union all
select 'table 2' tabl,
        case when max(age) > 60 then 'RED' else 'GREEN' end 
  from  table2
union all
select 'table 3' tabl,
        case when max(age) > 60 then 'RED' else 'GREEN' end 
  from  table3;
```

Comment: case when max(age) > 60 then 'RED' else case when max(age) < 30 then 'GREEN' end

is it possible to also put a secondary criteria or even a third in between the else as I have done above? The syntax I've posted above is wrong.

Comment: @user1821973 yes of course. Your error is that you put else when. You just need when. Else is the "catch all" the one. Eg when max(age) > 60 then... When max(age) between 30 and 60 then... Etc with an optional else 'whatever' at the end.